# How to read text file to parameters

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I’ve file that contain the following pattern

```
aaaa0000   aaaa0000@gmail.com
bbbb0001   bbbb0001@gmail.com
…
```

I need to read the value from this file and put it to variable 
e.g.

1. **aaaa0000** should be **`user`**
2. **aaaa0001@gmail.com** should be **email**

when I try the following

```
while IFS= read -r file; do

[[ $email == *@* ]] && [[ $user==“%s%18d\n”]]
```

I don’t get the right values .
How should I change it to read the spreated user and email value to varibles?

Comment: Consider running code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking about it here. That would catch some of the obvious bits, like missing spaces around the second `==` and before the last `]]`, or the use of "smart quotes" as opposed to ASCII quotes. The other thing is that `[[ $foo == $bar ]]` doesn't assign to or modify `foo` -- it's *just* a comparison operator, and not one that recognizes `printf`/`scanf` placeholders; if you want to use extended test syntax to extract content from data, see BASH_REMATCH in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns#Regular_Expressions-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the names of the variables you want to parse content into as arguments to `read`:

```
while read -r user email; do
  echo "User <${user}> has email <${email}>"
done
```

For an extensive discussion, see [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Comment: I dont need to use IFS?

Comment: In this case, if you *want* a line to be split into multiple variables, then you *must not* set`IFS` to an empty string, since its value tells the shell which characters to use for that splitting.

Comment: ...on the other hand, if you wanted it to only split on tabs (for instance), you could set `IFS=$'\t'`, and then only tabs would be used for the separation, and spaces would be considered part of the values.

Comment: I try the code and its not working `while read -r user email; do
  echo "User <${user}> has email <${email}>"
done < <(awk -F ';' '{ print $1 }' "$users")` I've entry in the text file and its not printed when I execute the script  ...any idea ?

Comment: Without knowing the output from your `awk` script, it's hard to comment. That said, try replacing your process substitution with this: `<(printf '%s  %s\n' aaaa0000 aaaa0000@gmail.com
bbbb0001 bbbb0001@gmail.com)` -- that way the behavior is less dependent on things not given as part of the question. And if it still doesn't work, then we have a common starting point to debug from.

Comment: oh -- and if you're going to put it all on one line, you need a `;` before the `done`.

Comment: Ok thanks last question when I use the following `create user ${user} -p ${passwd} --emails ${email}` I got the wrong order . passwd is a constant , any idea why its not keep the right order ?

Comment: I got error ERROR  create user aaaa0000   paaaa0000@gmail.com faild since it should be like `create user aaaa0000  -p123 --emails paaaa0000@gmail.com`

Comment: I oepned new question and close this, see please if you can help :) thanks!https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46142299/shell-varible-are-not-passed-correctly